# Disks utility erase failed - potential hard drive damage

Tags: hard-drive, secure-erase

I bought a new Dell precision 3530 with Ubuntu and a 1TB secondary hard drive.  The secondary hard drive volume was not recognized so as a first step, I tried to format it by selected the erase data option (to start off fresh) in the Disks utility.  It first indicated that the process would take about 4 hours.  This gradually went up to 13 hours.  I left it running over night and in the morning, it seemed like the process failed.  The Disks utility was showing that the hard drive had a temperature of 44 degrees Celsius.  Is there anyway I can check if there has been any damage or corruption to the hard drive?  Could it have left my hard drive in an inconsistent or unusable state?  I now realize that there was no need to erase the data.  Would it fix it if I try to reformat without selecting the erase data option?

Thanks

Comment: Since you bought this new, this may be a warranty issue.

Comment: With the same Disks, click the hamburger icon and select SMART test to evaluate the drive's health.

Comment: Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and start gparted. Lay down a fresh GPT Partition Table (this will wipe the drive), then create a new ext4 partition. See if that works. Report back.

Comment: Hi All.  Thanks for the suggestions.  I tried the SMART test as suggested by @GabrielaGarcia and it is showing a status of OK.  However, whenever I access my harddrive, the fan is making quite a lot of noise.  Since this is a new laptop, I do not know if this is normal or indicative of some disk damage as I have no previous knowledge of the behavior of this laptop for reference.